# why am i getting attribute error for my program for find_all?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

i wrote this code where i wanted to scrape amazon for mobiles phones price

```
    import  requests
from  bs4 import BeautifulSoup
headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.198 Safari/537.36'}
r = requests.get('https://www.amazon.in/s?i=electronics&bbn=1805560031&rh=n%3A976419031%2Cn%3A976420031%2Cn%3A1389401031%2Cn%3A1389432031%2Cn%3A1805560031%2Cp_36%3A2500000-%2Cp_85%3A10440599031&hidden-keywords=smartphone&pf_rd_i=1389401031&pf_rd_m=A1K21FY43GMZF8&pf_rd_p=1256e9e9-b753-4049-b447-56796aba6c3f&pf_rd_r=ZQRE51ATVS9X2BTQYXWT&pf_rd_s=merchandised-search-20&pf_rd_t=101&ref=s9_acss_bw_cg_CPACSM20_8f1_w',headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content , 'html.parser')
a = soup.find_all(class_='sg-col-16-of-20 sg-col sg-col-8-of-12 sg-col-12-of-16')

price = [item.find(class_='a-price-whole').get_text() for item in a]
print(price)
```

i don't know why i am getting  attribute error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rl0kj.png)

[image: This is the Error i am getting]

Answer (score 0):

Because `find_all` method return a list, so

```
a = soup.find_all(class_='sg-col-16-of-20 sg-col sg-col-8-of-12 sg-col-12-of-16')
```

a is a `list` an yo calling `find_all` from a `list`

```
content = a.find_all(class_='a-price-whole')
```

#print(c)

You must use objects inside `a` to find other elements

So correct it to:

```
....
a = soup.find_all(class_='sg-col-16-of-20 sg-col sg-col-8-of-12 sg-col-12-of-16')
price = [item.find(class_='a-price-whole') for item in a]
print(price)
....
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
import  requests
from  bs4 import BeautifulSoup
headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.198 Safari/537.36'}
r = requests.get('https://www.amazon.in/s?i=electronics&bbn=1805560031&rh=n%3A976419031%2Cn%3A976420031%2Cn%3A1389401031%2Cn%3A1389432031%2Cn%3A1805560031%2Cp_36%3A2500000-%2Cp_85%3A10440599031&hidden-keywords=smartphone&pf_rd_i=1389401031&pf_rd_m=A1K21FY43GMZF8&pf_rd_p=1256e9e9-b753-4049-b447-56796aba6c3f&pf_rd_r=ZQRE51ATVS9X2BTQYXWT&pf_rd_s=merchandised-search-20&pf_rd_t=101&ref=s9_acss_bw_cg_CPACSM20_8f1_w',headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content , 'html.parser')
a = soup.find_all(class_='sg-col-16-of-20 sg-col sg-col-8-of-12 sg-col-12-of-16')

price = [item.find(class_='a-price-whole') for item in a]

print(price)
```